# Error while creating a DataStream in Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Error while creating a **DataStream** using **fromElements** function

Below is the expeption -

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to deserialize an element from
>   the source. If you are using user-defined serialization (Value and
>   Writable types), check the serialization functions. Serializer is
>   org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.kryo.KryoSerializer@599fcdda
>           at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.FromElementsFunction.run(FromElementsFunction.java:121)
>           at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:58)
>           at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask.run(SourceStreamTask.java:55)
>           at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:218)
>           at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:584)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: What is the type you're providing to the `fromElements` method?

Comment: it's InputStreamReader

Comment: Below is the sample -
private static DataStream<InputStreamReader> getStream(StreamExecutionEnvironment env) {
InputStreamReader isr=null;
try {
URL url = new URL("http://www.ex.in/res");
HttpURLConnection httpconn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
if (httpconn.getResponseCode() != 200)
throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + httpconn.getResponseCode());
isr = new InputStreamReader((httpconn.getInputStream()));
} catch (Exception e){}
return env.fromElements(isr);
}

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to process `InputStreamReader` tuples? I guess there is some miss understanding here. The generic type specifies the type of the data you want to process. For example

```
DataStream<Integer> intStream = env.fromElements(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

Generate a finite data stream with 5 `Integer` tuples. I assume that you actually want to use an `InputStreamReader` to generate the actual tuples.

If you want to read via `HttpURLConnection` you could implement your own `SourceFunction` (or `RichSourceFunction`) as follows (replace `OUT` with you actual data type you want to use -- also consider Flinks `Tuple0` to `Tuple25` types):

```java
env.addSource(new SourceFunction<OUT> {
    private volatile boolean isRunning = true;

    @Override
    public void run(SourceContext<OUT> ctx) {
        InputStreamReader isr = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL("ex.in/res");
            HttpURLConnection httpconn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            if (httpconn.getResponseCode() != 200)
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + httpconn.getResponseCode());
            isr = new InputStreamReader((httpconn.getInputStream()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // clean up; log error
            return;
        }

        while(isRunning) {
            OUT tuple = ... // get data from isr
            ctx.collect(tuple);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void cancel() {
         this.isRunning = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: I am very much new to Flink. I am trying to read a Web log which is accessible through a HTTP URL. Hence I was trying that way. Which methods/objects does Flink provide in order to enable users to read HTTP streams?

Comment: Maybe it would make sense for you to implement a custom source. Just have a look at the `SourceFunction` interface. The `SourceContext` from the `run()` method allows you to emit elements.

Comment: Just extend my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a `DataStream<InputStreamReader>` with `fromElements` since the `InputStreamReader` is not serializable. That's required by the `fromElements` method. Furthermore, it probably does not make so much sense to work on `InputStreamReaders`. I guess it would be better to simply read the data from the `HttpURLConnection` and then continue working on this data.